# Trouble with passing Tkinter values to variables

Tags: python, tkinter

My tk section gets user entered text (string1, string2, string3, and string4) but does not pass it onto the 4 variables in the main section of my program. It does prompt for the text items, but the button doesn't close and the print statements do not execute.

I've tried a simpler version of this with 3 text entries and can print those in the main program.

```
def get_user_inputs():
    #Prompts user for four strings, stores them in variables, and returns them.
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Enter Four Strings")

    # String variables to store user input
    string_var1 = StringVar()
    string_var2 = StringVar()
    string_var3 = StringVar()
    string_var4 = StringVar()

    # Labels and entry fields
    label1 = Label(root, text="Enter string 1:")
    label1.pack()
    entry1 = Entry(root, textvariable=string_var1)
    entry1.pack()

    label2 = Label(root, text="Enter string 2:")
    label2.pack()
    entry2 = Entry(root, textvariable=string_var2)
    entry2.pack()

    label3 = Label(root, text="Enter string 3:")
    label3.pack()
    entry3 = Entry(root, textvariable=string_var3)
    entry3.pack()

    label4 = Label(root, text="Enter string 4:")
    label4.pack()
    entry4 = Entry(root, textvariable=string_var4)
    entry4.pack()

    # Button to retrieve input
    def get_and_close():
        string1 = string_var1.get()
        string2 = string_var2.get()
        string3 = string_var3.get()
        string4 = string_var4.get()
        return string1, string2, string3, string4  # Removed root.destroy() from here?

    button = Button(root, text="Enter", command=get_and_close)
    button.pack()

# Main event loop (after button definition)
    root.mainloop()  # Start event loop and wait for user input

# Retrieve user input after window closes
    return get_and_close()  # Call the get_and_close function

# Main program (outside the function)
string1, string2, string3, string4 = get_user_inputs()  # Get user input

# assign text values to variables
date_range_dor= string1
output_filename = string2
post_filename = string3 
post_filedate = string4

print("Date Range: ",date_range_dor)
print("Output Summary filename: ",output_filename)
print("Output POST filename: ",post_filename)
print("POST date variable: ",post_filedate)
```

Comment: The shown code wouldn't even run (`return` outside of a function, `get_and_close` not defined in module namespace).

Comment: `get_user_inputs()` doesn't return anything. What are you expecting to assign to `string1, string2, string3, string4`?

Comment: Did the indentation get messed up when you copied the code to SO?

Comment: @Barmar - yes, had a few indentations messed up with the copy.

Comment: @MichaelButscher - the return is now inside function get_user_inputs()

Comment: Obviously I am very new at this . . . some of my first efforts with Tkinter

Comment: If you want us to help, repost the code with correct indentation.

Comment: To make the button close the window, replace in `Button(...)` call the `command=get_and_close` by `command=root.destroy`.

Answer (score 1):

> gets user entered text (string1, string2, string3, and string4) but
> does not pass it onto the 4 variables in the main section of my
> program. It does prompt for the text items, but the button doesn't
> close and the print statements do not execute.

The problem can be fixed.

- Move `date_range_dor`, `output_filename`, `post_filename`,
  `post_filedate` and the rest of prints to inside of `get_and_close()`
  function.
- Add `root.after` and `root.destroy` inside of `get_and_close()`
- Call the `get_user_inputs()` function at the bottom.

Snippet

```
    # Button to retrieve input
    def get_and_close():
        string1 = string_var1.get()
        string2 = string_var2.get()
        string3 = string_var3.get()
        string4 = string_var4.get()
         
        date_range_dor = string1
        output_filename = string2
        post_filename = string3 
        post_filedate = string4

        print(f"Date Range: {string1}")
        print(f"Output Summary filename: {string2}")
        print(f"Output POST filename: {string3}")
        print(f"POST date variable: {string4}")
        
        root.after(1000, root.destroy)         
        return string1, string2, string3, string4  # Removed root.destroy() from here?          
    
    button = tk.Button(root, text="Enter", command=get_and_close)
    button.pack()
    
get_user_inputs()
```

After one second, it will close window.

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `global` variables for `string1, string2, string3, string4`. Also, you need to use `root.destroy()` to close the window once you press `Enter`.
The button command function should modify the global variables instead of returning the collected variables as the return value from the command function is not accessed anywhere. These global variables need to be passed down to the `get_user_inputs()` and `get_and_close()` functions so that they can be modified by these functions. Here is the modified code, which is working for me:

```
def get_user_inputs():
    #Prompts user for four strings, stores them in variables, and returns them.
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Enter Four Strings")

    global string1,string2, string3, string4

    # String variables to store user input
    string_var1 = StringVar()
    string_var2 = StringVar()
    string_var3 = StringVar()
    string_var4 = StringVar()

    # Labels and entry fields
    label1 = Label(root, text="Enter string 1:")
    label1.pack()
    entry1 = Entry(root, textvariable=string_var1)
    entry1.pack()

    label2 = Label(root, text="Enter string 2:")
    label2.pack()
    entry2 = Entry(root, textvariable=string_var2)
    entry2.pack()

    label3 = Label(root, text="Enter string 3:")
    label3.pack()
    entry3 = Entry(root, textvariable=string_var3)
    entry3.pack()

    label4 = Label(root, text="Enter string 4:")
    label4.pack()
    entry4 = Entry(root, textvariable=string_var4)
    entry4.pack()

    # Button to retrieve input
    def get_and_close():
        global string1,string2, string3, string4
        string1 = string_var1.get()
        string2 = string_var2.get()
        string3 = string_var3.get()
        string4 = string_var4.get()
        root.destroy()
        #return string1, string2, string3, string4  # Removed root.destroy() from here?. 
        #Commented out this return statement as the return values are not captured anywhere
        
    
    button = Button(root, text="Enter", command=get_and_close)
    button.pack()

# Main event loop (after button definition)
    root.mainloop()  # Start event loop and wait for user input
        
#Retrieve user input after window closes
    return string1, string2, string3, string4 #Return the modified values
    #return get_and_close()  # Call the get_and_close function

#Main program (outside the function)
string1 = string2 = string3 = string4=None #initializing the variables with global scope
string1, string2, string3, string4 = get_user_inputs()  # Get user input

# assign text values to variables
date_range_dor= string1
output_filename = string2
post_filename = string3 
post_filedate = string4

print("Date Range: ",date_range_dor)
print("Output Summary filename: ",output_filename)
print("Output POST filename: ",post_filename)
print("POST date variable: ",post_filedate)
```

### Here is how the window and the console look like:

Window :

[image]

Console:

[image]

Hope this helps!